# <aura:iteration> Display unique value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-iteration

I have an iteration like this;

```
<aura:iteration items="{! xy.typeList }" var="sp" indexVar="x" >
    <aura:If isTrue="{!sp.desc}"> 
        {! sp.desc } {! ( greaterthan(subtract(pq.type2.length, 1), x) ? ',' : '' ) }
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            xxx
        </aura:set>
    </aura:If>
</aura:iteration>
```

I want to print just one 'xxx' if the  is false on the iteration. currently if it hits two times, it displays 'xxx xxx'. I just want to display just once

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that directly in markup. You'll need to massage your data so that the output is correct.